# R: Plotting arc between two 3d points with RGL

Tags: r, rgl

I have created a 3d sphere with `rgl.spheres()` using rgl, and plotted two point on the surface of the sphere. Does anyone know how to draw an arc between these two point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to calculate points along the arc, and use `lines3d` to draw the curve.  You might want to move the arc a little bit outside
the sphere to avoid problems if they intersect:  neither one is really
spherical, so intersections are likely to look ugly.

For example,

```
r <- 1.3
center <- matrix(1:3, ncol=3)
library(rgl)
open3d()
spheres3d(center, radius = r, col = "white")
# A couple of random points
pts <- matrix(rnorm(6, mean=c(center, center)), ncol = 3)
# Set the radius to 1.001*r
setlen <- function(pt) {
  center + 1.001*r*(pt - center)/sqrt(sum((pt - center)^2))
}
pts <- t(apply(pts, 1, setlen))
points3d(pts, col = "black")

# Now draw the arc
n <- 20
frac <- seq(0, 1, len = n)
arc <- matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = n)
for (i in seq_along(frac)) {
  # First a segment
  arc[i,] <- frac[i]*pts[1,] + (1-frac[i])*pts[2,]
  # Now set the radius
  arc[i,] <- setlen(arc[i,])
}
lines3d(arc, col = "red")
```

This produces

[image]

Edited to add:

The very latest version of rgl (0.100.5, only currently available on R-forge) has a new function `arc3d`.  With that version the code to draw the image can be simplified to

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
spheres3d(center, radius = r, col = "white")
points3d(pts, col = "black")
arc3d(pts[1,], pts[2,], center, col = "red")
```

If the points are at different distances from `center`, it will join them
with an arc from a logarithmic spiral instead of a circular arc.